# What's the current SU password on version 15.04?

Tags: password, root

I want to change the SU password but it wont let me, what's the  current SU password on version 15.04?  It is a new install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is the same as your user password, type:

```
sudo su
```

and enter your user password

root account is disabled in ubuntu for security purposes (there is no root password)

Comment: Awesome mchid, that does it,  thank you for your help !!

Comment: @JackRam cool, you can accept the answer by clicking the icon on the left to close it out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no root password, but you can login as root with either `sudo su` or `sudo -i`.

After that, you can set the root password with `passwd` if you so wish.